# How to have a function in a macro return the name of the html class for Google tags?

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

I have a website that contains the following:

```
<ul class="top">
 <li class="first menu">...</li>
 <li class="some menu">...</li>
 <li class="another menu">...</li>
 <li class="last menu">...</li>
</ul>
```

I have been trying to write a function in a macro (Google tag manager) that will return "another menu"or "first menu", or any menu depending which menu's element was clicked.  I tried this example code to make sure things *can* work:

```
  function() {
    var now = new Date();
    return now.getTime();
  }
```

It works fine, so all I need to do is modify the function until it does what I want it to do.  I have tried the following ideas from similar questions here, but all of them result in **undefined** - **undefined** (rather than **string** - '**some menu**'):

```
function() {
        var now= $(this).attr("class");
return now;
}
```

---

```
var gtval = aData[4];
$(gtval).attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
```

---

```
var gtval = aData[4];
$($.trim(gtval)).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
```

---

```
var gtval = aData[4];
var classList = gtval.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
return classList;
```

---

```
return $('selector').attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
```

---

```
return document.getElementsByClassName(names);
```

It doesn't seem like it would be terribly difficult to accomplish what I want, I just can't figure out how to do it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tomek already answered this, but if you still want to get the value in a macro remember the DOM must be loaded before it can be queried, so this will not work on pageload/gtm.load or the default "all pages" rule (your rule would have to listen to gtm.dom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers, but I couldn't get them to work. Fortunately, my co-worker figured out how to do it. I'm posting her fix here, that it may benefit others:

```
function() {
 var $element = $({{element}});
 return $element.closest("li").attr("class");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do not need to use jquery to accomplish this. You could instead use "Click Listener" Tag if an element in the list is not very complex. If you add "Click Listener" Tag to your container it will catch all clicks on any element on your webpage, giving you basic info about it (including class in element.class macro). To check if it will solve your problem, just add "Click Listener" to your container, go into debug mode, go to your webpage, click on the list element and check what info will be stored in element.class macro on the gtm.click event.

If you have something rather complex inside your list element, element.class on click event will most probably return you something stupid. To handle your problem in such situation indeed you could use jquery but in a slightly different manner. You shouldn't call jquery function on click event as GTM will  not pass you clicked element into your script. I suggest to add a Tag to your website which contains such a script.

```
$('li').click(function(){
  dataLayer.push({
    'event' : 'li_class_click' // optional, to be used if you want do 
                               // something specific on moment of click
    'li_class' : $(this).attr('class')
  })
});
```

With such tag you will add a function call to each li element. After click this function will place in dataLayer a desired class name. You could further place it in a macro. Additionally, if you would like to do something as a response to a click, you just need to add `'event':'li_class_click'` to dataLayer push and place all the magic in another tag fired only on `li_class_click event`.